# Relative path when opening a file in Chrome via PowerShell

Tags: windows, google-chrome, powershell, path

I'm on Windows 10, and I'm trying to open a file with Chrome, however, PS always ends up sending it the relative path.

I'm running commands inside a directory called `phy`, and here is it's structure (relevant parts):

```
.
├── defaults.json
└── docs
    ├── 11-01-physics-rotation-and-revolution.html
    └── 11-09-physics-mechanical-properties-of-materials.html
```

I tried each of the following commands in several ways.

- without Chrome on my PATH
- with Chrome on my PATH after reboot (specifically, the folder `C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application` is on my user PATH)
- using `start chrome` instead of `chrome`
- with `\` instead of `/`

```
PS> chrome ./docs/11-09-physics-mechanical-properties-of-materials.html
PS> chrome ./docs/11-09-physics-mechanical-properties-of-materials.html
PS> chrome docs/11-09-physics-mechanical-properties-of-materials.html
PS> chrome Resolve-Path ./docs/11-09-physics-mechanical-properties-of-materials.html
PS> chrome Convert-Path ./docs/11-09-physics-mechanical-properties-of-materials.html
PS> Resolve-Path ./docs/11-09-physics-mechanical-properties-of-materials.html | chrome
PS> Convert-Path ./docs/11-09-physics-mechanical-properties-of-materials.html | chrome
```

After executing, the address bar of Chrome has either `./docs/11-09-physics-mechanical-properties-of-materials.html` (not the expanded version, it literally gets the `.` character), `Resolve-Path`, `Convert-Path`, or it's blank and I get the New Tab page.

The following commands work as expected:

```
PS> chrome
PS> chrome google.com
PS> chrome D:\username\Documents\edu\College\attempt-2\Exams\JEE\Notes\self\phy\docs\11-09-physics-mechanical-properties-of-materials.html  # this is the full path to the aforementioned phys directory
```

How do I get it to convert a relative path to an absolute one? Coming from Ubuntu, bash does this pretty much automatically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usage of `Convert-Path` is apparently correct. However, that should be in parenthesis:

```
PS> chrome (Convert-Path ./docs/11-09-physics-mechanical-properties-of-materials.html)
```

Source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/71664945/10907280